# Best approach to compress Less files and JS files

Tags: javascript, less

It's not a poll, as I know it's not what stackoverflow is for it's more that I need a direction to handle my frontend elements.

I'm creating websites that can be hosted on sharedhost or dedicated server (some are on Prestashop, other on Joomla, other with Laravel). So using something like Gulp or Grunt is hard (for the sharedhost part). I try to figure what is the best option to compress / minify / auto-prefix my less files and JS files.

Do all of you use tools like Gulp (and how do you handle host that doesn't provide nodejs or commande line) or can it be done directly within an IDE like PHPStorm ?

Thanks for your tips

Comment: *I know it's not what stackoverflow is for*. You have answered your own question.

Comment: Why do you want to optimize the files on the server-side? This is very uncommon, you can upload files using Grunt. Optimize locally and then upload the files.

Comment: Terry : But where to ask this kind of question to get the right direction ?

Comment: I don't think this question is necessarily off-topic, but it probably needs more description of the problem and how you have tried to solve it. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. **Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.**" (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Stuart : Sorry if my explanation wasn't clear. I work on some shared hosts, and I use Less css on them. So I need to find a good way to convert them to css and compress them without Gulp because these kind of server doesn't allow it... And I find the fact of doing it localy and uploading them to painfull when working on dozens of files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grunt is your answer, properly setted for your tasks could do compress / minify / auto-prefix and also copy to a prod folder for example, orupload using sftp or ftp to your site without involving any manual pain, you dont have to do it in the server, just locally, and would be a real pain if grunt didnt include so many plugins for doing, literally, all you need.